# Can we link an executable file in a html document?

Tags: html, executable

I have a image editing software and I am trying to run this software inside a webpage in frames, so that the user first downloads the software and this software is stored and installed in a targeted folder and the html document accesses this location inside frames, i have tried linking using `<object>` and `<embed>` tag, but it gives option to download the executable whereas I want it to work within the web page, so is there any option so that I can link this executable such that it runs inside my webpage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open an exe file through a link in a HTML file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252913/open-an-exe-file-through-a-link-in-a-html-file)

Comment: From what I can see, you want the web page to access the data on the local client machine?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to execute EXE files using ActiveXObject and IE. Example:

```
var cmdShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var myPath = '"C:\\New Folder\\myExe.exe"';
cmdShell.Run(myPath , 1, true);
```

Even that is unlikely to work in the real world - too many rogue ActiveX controls mean that support for them even in IE is normally disabled.

The chances of your getting this to work at all outside a corporate environment where the use of a specific ActiveX control can be mandated are very slim.

Outside this, there is no guarantee that the required EXE file even exists - browsers run on Mac, Linux, mobile devices and even internet enabled fridges.

If it was possible, it would be a great safety flaw.