# How do I run a .exe file created from visual studio solution on a webpage?

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, web

How do I run a .exe file created from visual studio solution with dependency files on a webpage?
If I run the .exe directly like this:

```
<a href="Folder/App.exe" type="application/octet-stream">Check</a>
```

the first form opens, but then the next form doesn't open, but I have all the dependency files on the folder.

Opening the .exe file is not the problem but .exe depends on DLLs which are not working.

Comment: You need the client to download all of the DLLs.

Comment: Web pages "run" on a client's browser. A browser won't execute exe files. It would be a huge security problem if they did.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403203/php-how-do-i-start-an-external-program-running-having-trouble-with-system-and

Comment: @SLaks even if the client downloads all the DLLs, how can I fetch the values back to the webpage?

Comment: You can't.  You should rewrite your UI in Javascript.

Comment: @SLaks My application uses usb HID. so can't be done using javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open an exe file through a link in a HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252913/open-an-exe-file-through-a-link-in-a-html-file)

Comment: @HereticMonkey As I said in the body, I am able to open the .exe file but not the DLLs. I don't see anything similar in the post you mentioned.

Comment: It says it's not possible in the duplicate... and it's still not possible, as you're finding out. I don't believe that it's working as you say it is, unless you're running the HTML file locally.

Comment: The .exe file is opening since the file is on the server.

Comment: @masonCOD are you asking how you can make it such that your .exe pulls data from a webpage as a dependency or vis versa?

Comment: This is a huge security hole.  I cannot think of any browser that allows an executable to run within the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web browser doesn't have the capability to "Run" an .exe extension. The only way you're going to make this run in a browser is to re-write it in a language that your browser can understand. HTML, JavaScript, etc....