# TAPI call from web page

Tags: php, laravel, phone-call, tapi

I got a customer service team who'd like to click on a telephone number in a service request ticket and it would dial the call automatically for them rather than they manually dialling the number on the screen with from phone.

I got a PHP 7.1 web application and all the users uses Windows desktops.

I was looking in to TAPI interface by Microsoft which seems to be possible to get this done after the users installed the TAPI exe to their computer.
Now what Im trying to do is try to call the exe from web application with the phone number, similarly to `mailto:email@email.com`.

Is it possible to do this?

This is not a duplicate of [Open an exe file through a link in a HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252913/open-an-exe-file-through-a-link-in-a-html-file) because I'm asking about calling a exe with a parameter (telephone number) and I'm looking for similar format as 'mailto'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open an exe file through a link in a HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252913/open-an-exe-file-through-a-link-in-a-html-file)

Comment: I think it's not possible.

Comment: @SatishSaini I already had a look in to that question before. Thats not what I'm looking for I'm afraid.

Comment: @NarayanSharma, Why do you think that? We are able to open email clients, browsers from html (which are exe files) also apple website is able to open iTunes application from their webpage.

Comment: If you could do that, wouldn't this mean that people can open any software in your desktop using php/html? which will be considered as a very huge security risk? idk

Comment: One simple hint is when you click on (contact number) it request goes to the server (PHP file), Create one .sh file and type required command(which will open your required application) and from your PHP file execute that .sh file. It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

The telephone equivalent of "mailto" is "tel":

```
<a href="tel:+491234567">Dial</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a quick answer. I might come back to edit it later, but what you want is not that difficult: you need the exe to register itself as a protocol handler. Here is the MSDN page with all the info: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)